# Is it possible to have #ifdef,#endif in functions's argument in c?

Tags: c, stm32

Hello I wanted to know if it is possible to have preprocessor language ine the argument of a function.

Something like this :

```
static void OnTxData( 
#ifdef MODULE1
    TxParams_t* params
#else
    Tx2Params_t* params
#endif
                       )
{
...
}
```

Comment: It's possible, and I confess I've done it myself.  On the other hand, it's a bad habit, because it's terribly confusing.

Comment: It will work fine like that. No problem. But it may generated "hard to read" code.

Comment: @SteveSummit I understand from your words that it is not advised do you know why ?

Comment: You could use a `typedef` that was defined to be either `TxParams_t` or `Tx2Params_t` using an `#ifdef`

Comment: Steve Summit already said why: It's confusing. There's also the problem that you probably have to do it for multiple functions, and thus have a Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) problem.

Comment: Better `ifdef` the whole function declaration. So ok, a bit more to type but less confusion.

Comment: The answer is: Yes. Whether it's a good idea can not be answered from the little information given. It all depends on the problem you are trying to solve...

Comment: Try to avoid using `#ifdef` in this way. It is easy for a `#else` or a `#endif` to be deleted and thus alter your code dramatically and once its gone how do you know where to put it back? Its far better to separate code into different files where the entire contents are compiled or ignored depending on whether they apply to `MODULE1` or not

Comment: That's perfectly valid, but that's not an acceptable way of defining functions. You could defjine a new union type with the two types `TxParams_t*, Tx2Params_t*` and use it as the function argument or you can use only single type `TxParams_t` and conditionally define it (`#ifdef`'magic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hard to read:

```
static void OnTxData( 
#ifdef MODULE1
    TxParams_t* params
#else
    Tx2Params_t* params
#endif
                       )
{
...
}
```

```
#ifdef MODULE1
    #define TX_Params TxParams_t
#else
    #define TX_Params Tx2Params_t
#endif

static void OnTxData( TX_Params *prams)
{
...
}
```

or

```
#ifdef MODULE1
    typedef TxParams_t TX_Params
#else
    typedef Tx2Params_t TX_Params
#endif

static void OnTxData( TX_Params *prams)
{
...
}
```

or (IMO worse)

```
#ifdef MODULE1
static void OnTxData( TxParams_t *prams)
#else
static void OnTxData( Tx2Params_t *prams)
#endif
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use these *literally anywhere* (as long as they go on their own line). The preprocessor "works these out" *before* the rest of the compiler compiles anything.

So if `MODULE1` is defined then this is the code that gets compiled:

```
static void OnTxData( 
    TxParams_t* params
                       )
{
...
}
```

and if it's not defined, then this is the code that gets compiled:

```
static void OnTxData( 
    Tx2Params_t* params
                       )
{
...
}
```

Comment: We know that it will work but it is  very hard to read